# See existing indexes in MongoDB using mongoid

Tags: mongoid, indexing

I'd like to see the existing indexes used by MongoDB. Can I do the equivalent of

```
$ mongod
> use my_db
> db.system.indexes.find()
```

using Mongoid?

```
$ rails console
> ?
```

Would be convenient from my heroku apps using MongoHQ. Thanks!

Answer (score 32):

You can get at the underlying indexes for a Mongoid model through its `collection`.

```
> YourModel.collection.indexes
```

This reaches down into the moped driver (in Mongoid 3). See http://mongoid.org/en/moped/docs/driver.html

Comment: thanks. `Order.collection.indexes.each {|i| puts i.inspect};false` yields a readable results

Comment: Order.collection.indexes.to_a yields a a readable result more easily

Comment: `YourModel.collection.indexes.to_a` seems to be enough.

Answer (score 1):

To put Steve's answer to use, I added it to a module to do "common things":

```
module CommonModelMethods
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern
  class_methods do
    def show_indexes
      self.collection.indexes.to_a.collect{|i| i[:key]}
    end
  end
end
```

That module can then be included in your class (useful during development):

```
class WaterSupply
  include Mongoid::Document
  include CommonModelMethods
  ...
end
```

Which can result in something like this in the console:

```
2.4.5 :031 > WaterSupply.show_indexes
 => [{"_id"=>1}, {"location"=>"2dsphere"}, {"address"=>1}, {"organization_id"=>1, "address"=>1}]
```