# To get/show indexes of a collection using Mongoid 2.4

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

in `mongo` console, I can execute `db.collection.getIndexes()` to view all the indices defined for a particular collection.

What is the `mongoid` equivalent of the above query?

Taking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12193591/see-existing-indexes-in-mongodb-using-mongoid) reference

I tried:

`CollectionName.collection.getIndexes()`

but it has no method as such. It seems like you can perform the above query in `mongoid 3.0` but not in `mongoid 2.4`.

Comment: It's not called `getIndexes`. It's just `indexes` according to the docs. Have you tried that? While I can't confirm it's there it the specific build you have, it's been in the underlying MongoDb driver, Moped, for a very long time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally came across the command which fetches the indexes:

```
CollectionName.collection.index_information
```

But I wonder, why the above command is not mentioned anywhere in the documentation?

Answer (score 2):

If `CollectionName` is your model then `CollectionName.collection` will be a [`Moped::Collection`](http://rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/moped/Moped/Collection). To get at a collection's indexes from a `Moped::Collection` you use the [`indexes`](http://rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/moped/Moped/Collection#indexes-instance_method) method:

```
indexes = CollectionName.collection.indexes
```

Then you can use [`each`](http://rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/moped/Moped/Indexes#each-instance_method) to look at the indexes:

```
CollectionName.collection.indexes.each do |index|
  # index['key'] has the keys as a Hash
  # index['unique'] will be true for a unique index
  # ...
end
```

The [Mongoid API](http://rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/mongoid/frames) and [Moped API](http://rubydoc.info/github/mongoid/moped/frames) might be worth a review.

---

If you're in Mongoid2 land, then I think you'd have to use the standard low level MongoDB interface rather than Moped. In that case `CollectionName.collection.driver` would be a [`Mongo::Collection`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/mongo/Mongo/Collection) and the index methods would be:

- [`create_index`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/mongo/Mongo/Collection:create_index) and [`ensure_index`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/mongo/Mongo/Collection:ensure_index) for creating indexes.
- [`drop_index`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/mongo/Mongo/Collection:drop_index) for dropping an index.
- [`drop_indexes`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/mongo/Mongo/Collection:drop_indexes) for dropping all indexes at once.
- [`index_information`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/mongo/Mongo/Collection:index_information) for getting information about a collection's indexes.

In your case, you'd want to look at the `CollectionName.collection.driver.index_information` Hash.

Comment: I tried that, it threw an error: `undefined method 'indexes' for <Mongoid::Collection>`. I think, the method you are suggesting works in `mongoid 3.0 ` but not `2.4 or 2.6`

Comment: I just added a Mongoid 2 update but I had to make some guesses based on the source since I don't have Mongoid 2 set up anywhere.